# Rails Hidden Field Not Saving Params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using an if/else statement in my form to set some fields invisibly if a `@goal` variable is present, but to allow them to set it using a dropdown if it isn't.

My HTML/ERB looks like this:

```
  <% if @goal %>
    <%= hidden_field :area_id, value: @goal.area_id %>
    <%= hidden_field :goal_id, value: @goal.id %>
  <% else %>
    <section id="milestone-associations">
      <h4 class="color-areafont-weight-bold border-bottom-area text-center pb-1">
        Associations
      </h4>
      <div class="row">
        <% area_array = [] %>
        <% Area.where(user_id: current_user.id, archived: false).each do |area| %>
          <% area_array << [area.name, area.id] %>
        <% end %>

        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
          <label for="orangeForm-area" class="mb-0">Which key area is this in?</label>
          <%= f.input :area_id, label: false, prompt: "Select Key Area", input_html: { class: 'mdb-select md-form mt-0', style: "margin-top: 0px" }, collection: area_array %>
        </div>

        <% goals_array = [] %>
        <% Goal.where(user_id: current_user.id, archived: false).each do |goal| %>
          <% goals_array << [goal.area.name + " :: " + goal.name, goal.id] %>
        <% end %>

        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
          <label for="orangeForm-goal" class="mb-0">Is this associated with a goal?</label>
          <%= f.input :goal_id, label: false, prompt: "Select Goal", input_html: { class: 'mdb-select md-form mt-0', style: "margin-top: 0px" }, collection: goals_array.sort %>
        </div>
      </div> <!-- row -->
    </section>
  <% end %>
```

The if/else is working, but something in the hidden fields isn't working properly.  Here's what it shows up as in the server:

> Processing by MilestonesController#create as HTML   Parameters:
> {"utf8"=>"✓",
> "authenticity_token"=>"nehWSkm4CnLsnb7aedchtwLixxYljCZ9AwdQlh82Rnk/QCYfWCb7tP0W7x8CaI1cXwjbYF6KF0Zi6LpW8gH2qg==",
> "milestone"=>{"name"=>"Create More Stuff", "description"=>"",
> "official_start_date"=>"26 November, 2020", "external_due_date"=>"",
> "notes"=>""}, "area_id"=>{"{:value=>3}"=>""},
> "goal_id"=>{"{:value=>6}"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create Milestone"}

First question:  Why are the `goal_id` and `area_id` outside the {} for the new milestone?

Second question:  Why are they showing up as {:value=>3}?  I have tried removing the "value: " from my erb, but it yields this weirdness instead:

> Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
> "authenticity_token"=>"X1U/ddcpAh3Jcwj1c/B3tETStmfWk70FeUaHkdRzOlH9/U8gxrfz29j4WTAIT9tfGTiqEa2VjD4YqW1ROUSKgg==",
> "milestone"=>{"name"=>"Testy", "description"=>"",
> "official_start_date"=>"17 November, 2020", "external_due_date"=>"",
> "notes"=>""}, "area_id"=>{"3"=>""}, "goal_id"=>{"2"=>""},
> "commit"=>"Create Milestone"}

How can I get this to save properly?

Comment: Seems like you are using form field? Have you tried using f.hidden_field :goal_id ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@axel is right, you need to attach your `hidden_field` call to your form instance, `f` in this case. If you want the hidden inputs to build properly but not be a part of the milestone you should be using `hidden_field_tag` instead of `hidden_field`.

So either

```
    <%= f.hidden_field :area_id %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :goal_id %>
```

or

```
    <%= hidden_field_tag :area_id, value: @goal.area_id %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :goal_id, value: @goal.id %>
```

Comment: Argh.  The braindead mistakes always hurt the most.  Thank you!